# Closing and opening two model pop-ups subsequently on a Button's Click event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, django-models

I am using a JQuery to open and close a model pop-up.

```
//Function to open pop-up

 function UserSignupModalpopupFromSubDomain(guid,title)
{
    var srcFile = "../ModelPopup/SignUpPopup.aspx"; 
 if (guid) srcFile += '?location=' + guid+'&title=' + title; /* sample code to append a unique user ID to page called */ 
    var cFrame = new Element('iframe').setProperties({id:"iframe-signup", name:"iframe-signup", height:'420px', width:'584px', frameborder:"0", scrolling:"no"}).injectInside(document.body);
 $('iframe-signup').src = srcFile;
 customModalBox.htmlBox('iframe-signup', '', 'Sign up'); 
 $('mb_contents_Popup').addClass('yt-Panel-Primary_Popup');
 new Element('div').setHTML('&nbsp;').setProperty('id','mb_Error_Popup').injectTop($('mb_center_Popup'));

 new Element('h2').setHTML('Sign UP').setProperty('id','mb_Title_Popup').injectTop($('mb_contents_Popup'));
//    $('mb_center').setStyle('z-index','2005');
//    $('mb_overlay').setStyle('z-index','2004');



      $('mb_center_Popup').setStyle('z-index','2005');
   $('mb_overlay_Popup').setStyle('z-index','2004');



}


// pop-up close function

function UserSignUpClose() {
 $('mb_close_link').addEvent('click', function() {
  //if($('yt-UserProfileContent1')) $('yt-UserProfileContent1').remove();
  if($('iframe-signup')) $('iframe-signup').remove();
  if($('mb_Title_Popup')) $('mb_Title').remove();
  if($('mb_contents_Popup')) $('mb_contents_Popup').removeClass('yt-Panel-Primary_Popup');
  if($('mb_Error_Popup')) $('mb_Error_Popup').remove();
  $('mb_overlay_Popup').setStyle('z-index','1600');
 });
}
```

the close function is working fine when we use it with "Cancel" button of the pop-up window.

But i want to close a opened pop-up window and  open a new pop-up subsequently using same link button, and for this i tried as below at Page_load of aspx.cs page :

```
lnkButton.Attribues.Add("onClick","UserSignUpClose();");
lnkButton.Attribues["onClick"]+="UserSignupModalpopupFromSubDomain(location.href,document.title);";
```

but its not working 
While i tried to get  and  using its ids, i couldn't get its properties like id and type and innerHTML.

prior thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning `iframe-signup` , `mb_Error_Popup` and `mb_Title_Popup` as ids of the elements but you are using `$('iframe-signup').src = srcFile;`to slect the elements
The jQuery syntax for selecting elements with ids is as follows

```
$('#iframe-signup').src = srcFile;  // the # sign
```

do the same for all such selections